# Bulldogs! Gear damage vs. accuracy

Tags: fate, balance, statistics

I'm looking at ways to model weapons for my setting, and I like quite a few things what the [Bulldogs!](https://brennan-taylor.squarespace.com/#/bulldogs/) system does.

Basically, it's a system that has Fate's [Damage Floor](http://fate-srd.com/fate-system-toolkit/weapons-and-armor-alternatives#damage-floors-and-ceilings) (+Damage) combined with a straight up attack modifier (+Accuracy). However, the additional cost for each level of +Damage and +Accuracy is identical.

A quick calculation shows that the amount of extra damage seems to me to be about x2 normal damage for +Damage 2, and x4 normal damage for +Accuracy 2.

```
Attack 0 vs. Defense 0
+-----------------+--------+---------------+---------------+-----------+---------------+-------------+---------------+
|      Roll       | Chance | Normal Damage | Roll * Chance | +2 Damage | Roll * Chance | +2 Accuracy | Roll * Chance |
+-----------------+--------+---------------+---------------+-----------+---------------+-------------+---------------+
| -4              | 1,23   |             0 | 0,00          |         0 | 0,00          |           0 | 0,00          |
| -3              | 4,94   |             0 | 0,00          |         0 | 0,00          |           0 | 0,00          |
| -2              | 12,35  |             0 | 0,00          |         0 | 0,00          |           0 | 0,00          |
| -1              | 19,75  |             0 | 0,00          |         0 | 0,00          |           1 | 19,75         |
| 0               | 23,46  |             0 | 0,00          |         2 | 46,91         |           2 | 46,91         |
| 1               | 19,75  |             1 | 19,75         |         2 | 39,51         |           3 | 59,26         |
| 2               | 12,35  |             2 | 24,69         |         2 | 24,69         |           4 | 49,38         |
| 3               | 4,94   |             3 | 14,81         |         3 | 14,81         |           5 | 24,69         |
| 4               | 1,23   |             4 | 4,94          |         4 | 4,94          |           7 | 8,64          |
| Total/100 rolls |        |               | 64,20         |           | 130,86        |             | 208,64        |
+-----------------+--------+---------------+---------------+-----------+---------------+-------------+---------------+
```

Against higher level defense or armor (damage - armor rating) these disparaties can get even worse

```
Attack 0 vs. Defense 0 / Armor 2
+-----------------+--------+---------------+---------------+-----------+---------------+-------------+---------------+
|      Roll       | Chance | Normal Damage | Roll * Chance | +2 Damage | Roll * Chance | +2 Accuracy | Roll * Chance |
+-----------------+--------+---------------+---------------+-----------+---------------+-------------+---------------+
| -4              | 1,23   |             0 | 0,00          |         0 | 0,00          |           0 | 0,00          |
| -3              | 4,94   |             0 | 0,00          |         0 | 0,00          |           0 | 0,00          |
| -2              | 12,35  |             0 | 0,00          |         0 | 0,00          |           0 | 0,00          |
| -1              | 19,75  |             0 | 0,00          |         0 | 0,00          |           0 | 0,00          |
| 0               | 23,46  |             0 | 0,00          |         0 | 0,00          |           0 | 0,00          |
| 1               | 19,75  |             0 | 0,00          |         0 | 0,00          |           1 | 19,75         |
| 2               | 12,35  |             0 | 0,00          |         0 | 0,00          |           2 | 24,69         |
| 3               | 4,94   |             1 | 4,94          |         1 | 4,94          |           3 | 14,81         |
| 4               | 1,23   |             2 | 2,47          |         2 | 2,47          |           4 | 4,94          |
| Total/100 rolls |        |               | 7,41          |           | 7,41          |             | 64,20         |
+-----------------+--------+---------------+---------------+-----------+---------------+-------------+---------------+
```

Any oversights I made with the rules and subsequent calculations, or should +Accuracy cost (at least) twice as much as +Damage to keep things balanced ?

Comment: That's why they say Fate's not good for simulating realistic stuff ;)

Comment: Do you have a source for that ? ;P All joking aside, increasing the cost for accuracy points to 2 is a pretty simple fix, and you'll have damage and to hit modifiers comparable to other systems, but at Fate resolution (which IMHO is more than enough), and still get Fate's awesome narrative capabilities.

Comment: It's not really a realism thing.  Fate or not, you shouldn't have two things with the same cost if one of them is strictly better than the other one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doubling the cost of Accuracy (which is a crazily good augment in Fate) is at minimum an equitable way to balance it against a damage mod, and might not be enough.

Another approach is to have every point of +Damage actually provde +Damage 2.